# When to use and when not to use fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new in Android and I want to make an app, so, I was seeing a lot of tutorials and a few of them said that I need to use fragment, but in others tutorials say that if I want or only when my app is for Tablets. So, I really get me confuse about this, when I have to use fragment and when I not.

Please, explain to me when to use fragments or when not. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A fragment is an independent component which can be used by an
>   activity. A fragment encapsulate functionality so that it is easier to
>   reuse within activities and layouts.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments

> *but in others tutorials say that if I want or only when my app is for Tablets*

Those tutorials you mentioned probably meant this:

> Fragments make it easy to reuse components in different layouts, e.g.
>   you can build single-pane layouts for handsets (phones) and multi-pane
>   layouts for tablets. This is not limited to tablets; for example you
>   can use fragments also to support different layout for landscape and
>   portrait orientation on a smartphone.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_usage

When there is a big screen you don't want to leave empty space. When the screen is too small you don't want squeeze everything. The solution is to have 2 different layouts reusing as much code as possible. That is when `Fragments` are especially handy.

Answer (score 7):

For me I always use fragments in the sense that I can reuse it and my program will be compatible with a phone or a tablet.

But this answer is from Dummies for android development.

**Knowing when to use activities or fragments**

Both activities and fragments are central parts
of your user interface (UI) code. So how then do
you decide whether to put certain functionality
into a fragment or an activity?
If activities are the lunchbox of UI code, fragments
are its Tupperware. You can insert your
UI code directly into your lunchbox, but it would
be a bit of a mess and make the lunchbox code
hard to reuse. Put your UI code into your fragment
Tupperware instead, where you can shift
it from lunchbox to lunchbox as you need to use
it again.
If you’re absolutely certain that the code you’re
writing is specific to a given activity, put it
directly into an activity. But it you’re unsure,
put your UI code in a fragment. In most applications,
fragments contain all your UI code, and
your activities contain only the glue that binds
the fragments together.