# Using fragments but not for tablets

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments

I just read the Google lesson on fragments and I found it really useful. It shows clearly how to use fragments. I also checked this post 
[When to use and when not to use fragments in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647612/when-to-use-and-when-not-to-use-fragments-in-android)

and with my research on the net too, I understood that fragments are useful when one needs to define multipane layout for tablets and single-pane layout for phones, but I was wondering if there are another cases in which we can use fragments for phones (apart from listviews) ?

Comment: yes, you can use fragments for phone also without listviews(Ex: Viewpager)...

Comment: So can I use them to define a different layout, for the same activity (for example if I have other widgets that appear in the activity depending on some click events, can I use fragments to define a new layout or is it better just to add those widgets directly in the activity ?)

Comment: you can use individual layouts for fragments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fragments** are used like **containers** of activities.

Why do you need this? Again, it's simple.

Android 4 (ICS) supports both **Smartphones** and **Tablets**. This means the SAME application will be running on both a smartphone and a tablet, and they are likely to be very different.

**Tablets** has big screens, which will be empty or unused - unless you assign it properlly.

Thant means- Putting to activities on one fragment. like `Contacts List`, and `Contact Info`.

**Smatpone** will Display `contact List`, and on a touch- display the `contact's Info`.

On tablet, the user will still see the list and the info will be next to it.

Check this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)